# model run issue due "from keras.applications import Xception

Tags: python, keras

it gives following error

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
11 from keras.applications.inception_v3 import InceptionV3

```
 12 from tensorflow.keras.applications.xception import decode_predictions
```

---> 13 from keras.applications import Xception

```
 14 from keras.applications import DenseNet121, DenseNet169, DenseNet201

 15 from keras.optimizers import Adam, RMSprop,SGD
```

ImportError: cannot import name 'Xception' from 'keras.applications' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/applications/**init**.py)

Comment: you seem to b mixing Tensorflow and Keras imports

Comment: can you elaborate

Comment: only import things from tf.keras import ...

Comment: error begins from this line  " from keras.applications import Xception"
from keras.applications import DenseNet121, DenseNet169, DenseNet201
from keras.optimizers import Adam, RMSprop,SGD
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report,confusion_matrix,accuracy_score
from PIL import Image

Comment: please tell what is latest Xception  model